# Как правильно задавать форму элементам?

Tags: css, вёрстка, scss

И так, я хочу создать кнопку входа на сайт
У нее есть текст внутри и справа стрелочка вниз
Вот код на на данный момент:

```
<a href="#" class="login f_left">Sign in</a>
```

scss:

```
.login {
          display: block;
          color: $login_blue;
          font: $main_font;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 11px 24px;
          background: $login_light_blue url("../img/polygon.png") no-repeat scroll 76px 20px;
          line-height: 19px;
          @include transition(0.2s background);
          &:hover {
            background: $yellow url("../img/polygon.png") no-repeat scroll 76px 20px;
          }
        }
```

Эта стрелочка висит бэкграундом
Как видите, ширины фиксированной нет и форму я задал падингом
Но при таком раскладе в хроме выглядит кнопка сплющенной и стрелочка залазит на надпись
В мозиле выглядит хорошо

Вопрос: Правильно ли я верстаю кнопку?Может, нужно не падингом, а шириной и высотой или еще как то

Спасибо

Comment: а почему не использовать _кнопку_ вместо ссылки?

Comment: А то, что на картинке, мы должны угадать?

Comment: @Qwertiy прочитай внимательно вопрос и поймешь

Comment: @Grundy ну, так решил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не возникало наложений, поместите картинку рядом с надписью и управляйте её положением через стили. Отступ от надписи можно задать через паддинг, вертикальное положение - через относительное позиционирование и смещение. Например:

```css
.login {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 11px 24px;
  background: lightblue;
  line-height: 19px;
  transition: 0.2s background;
}
.login:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.login-img {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 12px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="login f_left"><span class="login-text">Sign in</span><img src="http://www.icomos.org/modules/mod_dmt_social/icons/linkedin_16.png" class="login-img"></a>
```

Comment: Я пробовал.
Решение нашел такое: я убрал все паддинги, картинку сделал absolute, а текст text-align и line-height

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов Можете итоговый код.показать?

Answer (score 0):

Используй псевдоэлемент `::after` для отображения стрелочки.